# Append <select> with AJAX call to XML

Tags: jquery, html, xml, ajax

Having issues with dynamically creating `<select>` tags and then populating them with XML values.

The jQuery appends a `<div>` with a select and then adds `<option>` tags from XML data.

My first XML / AJAX attempt.  Done some extensive reading but keep coming up short.

Here's an example of my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      function addSelect() {
        $("#myDiv").append(function(){
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "test.xml"
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
              $("#myDiv").append("<select id='mySelect'>");
              $(this).find('value').each(function(){
                var value = $(this).text();
                $("#mySelect".append("<option class='ddindent' value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
              });
              $("#myDiv").append("</select>");
            }
          });
        });
      }  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <a href="#" onClick="addSelect();">Add Select</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code, you're not reading the data from `xml`. Change `$(this)` to `$(xml)`:

```
$(xml).find('value').each(function(){
    var value = $(this).text();
    $("#mySelect").append("<option class='ddindent' value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
 });
```

**Edit:** Also changed `mySelect` to `#mySelect` as MMM pointed out, and fixed a syntax error (you hadn't closed the bracket around `mySelect`.

**Edit:** You have a few other oddities in your code. I have fixed them below:

```
function addSelect() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "test.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $("#myDiv").append("<select id='mySelect'>");
      $(xml).find('value').each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        $("#mySelect").append("<option class='ddindent' value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
      });
      $("#myDiv").append("</select>");
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$("mySelect".append("<option class='ddindent' value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
```

to

```
$("#mySelect").append("<option class='ddindent' value='" + value + "'>" + value + "</option>");
```

(added id selector)

Comment: There might be some other problems, there's a loose `$(xml)` for some reason.

Comment: Just typos from creating this code.  My production model doesn't have any of that stuff.  Just to be safe, I went through my code and, wouldn't you know it, I was missing a comma after `url: "test.xml"`  [me gusta]